# Why is file2 empty after 'cat file1>file2>file3'?

Tags: unix, cat

I am trying to execute the following command on UNIX.

```
$ cat file1>file2>file3
```

In the scenario where only the `file1` is present, what I think should happen is:

- `file2` should be created with the content of `file1`,
- and then `file3` from content of `file2`.

What actually happening is that:

- `file2` and `file3` get created and
- `file3` has the content of `file1`
- but `file2` does not — `file2` is created but it is blank/empty.

Can anyone explain why this happens?

Answer (score 6):

The shell interprets file redirections from left to right before running the command.  So when you enter

```
cat file1 > file2 > file3
```

it first does the redirection `> file2` -- creating or emptying `file2` and pointing stdout at it.  Then it does `> file 3`, creating or emptying `file3` and pointing stdout there.  Finally it runs the command `cat file1`, which reads `file1` and copies it to stdout.  Since stdout is (now) pointing at `file3`, `file3` ends up being a copy of that.  Since nothing was written to stdout when it pointed at `file2`, `file2` ends up empty.

Answer (score 4):

Others have explained why `file2` is empty (but, succinctly, it is because the redirection to `file3` replaces the redirection to `file2`, so `file2` is created or emptied but `file3` gets the data from `file1`).

If you want the output in two files, use `tee`:

```
cat file1 | tee file2 > file3
```

There are other ways to do that, including:

```
tee < file1 file2 > file3
```

which has a certain pleasing symmetry to it.  It also avoid the UUoC (Useless Use of `cat`) tag which the other is open to.  However, if you had a variable number of input files (0 or standard input, or many – meaning more than one — or you needed to process command line arguments), then `cat` would still be correct.  Note that `tee` can generate multiple files (so in some circumstances `cat "$@" | tee file1 file2 file3 >/dev/null` might make sense).

Answer (score 3):

`strace` gives the answer.

```
open("file2", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
dup2(3, 1)                        = 1
close(3)                          = 0
open("file3", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
dup2(3, 1)                        = 1
close(3)                          = 0
execve("/bin/cat", ["cat", "file1"], [/* 38 vars */]) = 0
```

The second dup2() closes the file descriptor associated with file2.  When cat runs, its stdout is file3.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening there is about how the standard input/output are managed.

You have `cat file1>file2>file3` and what it is doing here is almost the same as

```
cat file1 > file3
```

**Because file2 has it input redirected to the output**

So, even if your file2 has some text in it and you execute

```
cat file1 >  file2 > file3
```

The content of file3 will still be the content of file1, why ?

> CAT(1)                                                        User
>   Commands                                                        CAT(1)
>
> NAME
>          cat - concatenate files and print on the standard output
>
> DESCRIPTION
>          Concatenate FILE(s), **or standard input, to standard output.**

Check the **or** (or standard input to standard output). You're redirecting the standard input from file2 directly to the standard output.

Let's supose this scenario:

- file1 contains '123'
- file2 contains '456
- file3 doesn't exist

If you do `cat file1 > file2 > file3` then the contents of the files will be

- file1 contains '123'
- file2 is **empty**
- file3 contains '123'

**file2 send to the output what file1 send to the input**

Comment: `file2` will always be empty after the command, as the redirect clears it.

Comment: You're right. I misspelled the command when I was testing and executed `cat file1 >> file2 > file3` that's why I thought it will still keep its content